# RESTORE cannot process database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I design one application for backup and restore mechanism . When I press on the backup button it will successfully creates the backup file on the selected path. But when I want to restore the same database then that time it showing me an error

> RESTORE cannot process database 'email_client' because it is in use
>   bye this session. It is recommended that the master database be used
>   when performing this operation.RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally

so please provide coding for it

```
    private SqlCommand cmd;
    string sql = "";
    public Backup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=email_client;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("backup database email_client to disk ='" + textBox1.Text + "\\" + textBox2.Text + ".bak'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("done");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "Backup files(*.bak)|*.bak|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 0;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox3.Text = dlg.FileName;
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=email_client;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        try
        {

            sql = "alter database email_client set single_user with rollback immediate ;";
            sql += "RESTORE database email_client from disk='"+textBox3.Text+"'with replace;";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("done");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change database context before running the restore so either change the connection string from `Initial Catalog=email_client` to `initial_catalog=master` or include a `USE master;` statement at the start of the SQL command to switch context.